# solving a easy python challenge with for in loops

Tags: python

```
"""
Given a list of numbers and a number k, return whether any two numbers from the list add up to k.

For example, given [10, 15, 3, 7] and k of 17, return true since 10 + 7 is 17.

"""
numbers = [7, 15, 17]
k = 14

def add_to_k(numbers_list,k_value):
    truth = False
    for i in numbers_list:
        for l in numbers_list:
            added = i + l
            if added == k_value:
                num1 = i
                num2 = l
                truth = True
    if truth == True:
        print("Two numbers in the list added together is 17. " + str(num1) + " " + str(num2))
    else:
        print("Sorry, none give " + str(k_value))
add_to_k(numbers,k)
```

Following the prompt in the comments above, I made my attempt at this challenge. However, I realized that it would add the first number of the list twice, though I want to find two separate numbers that would add up to k. How would I go about changing this code? Thank you!

Comment: can the same number be in the list multiple times?

Comment: yes @Ruzihm    it can be like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should iterate over the array without the element that is being tested:

```
numbers = [7, 7, 17]
k = 14

def add_to_k(numbers_list,k_value):
    truth = False
    for i in numbers_list:
        y = numbers_list[:]  # fastest way to copy
        y.remove(i)
        for l in y:
            added = i + l
            if added == k_value:
                num1 = i
                num2 = l
                truth = True
    if truth == True:
        print("Two numbers in the list added together is "+str(k_value)+ ":  " + str(num1) + "," + str(num2))
    else:
        print("Sorry, none give " + str(k_value))
add_to_k(numbers,k)
```

Output:

```
 Two numbers in the list added together is 14:  7,7
```

Or if want another option:

```
import itertools as it
numbers = [12, 7, 17]
k = 19

def add_to_k(numbers_list,k_value):
    results = {i:sum(i) for i in list(it.combinations(numbers_list, 2))}
    if any(val==k_value for val in results.values()):
        print(f'Two numbers in the list added together is {k_value}:{list(results.keys())[list(results.values()).index(k_value)] }')
    else:
        print(f'Sorry, none give {k_value}')
    
add_to_k(numbers,k)
```

Output

```
Two numbers in the list added together is 19:(12, 7)
```

Comment: Nice, way more elegant than what I had

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was a method to do this, I completely forgot about splicing! Thanks again

Comment: Actually, if you do it this way and for example if I put one 7 at the end of the list, it would take 7 twice and give 14, and state that 7 as both of the numbers that add to 14, even though it may not appear twice on the list

Comment: Yeah @ewe, I just realized of that. I've edited my code. Hope it works for you :)!

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `combinations` from `itertools`:**

```
from itertools import combinations

numbers = [7, 15, 17, 10, 4]
k = 14

for t in combinations(numbers,2):
    if sum(t)==k:
        print(f"Two numbers in the list added together is {k}. {t[0]} {t[1]}")
        break
else:
    print(f"Sorry, none give {k}")
```

**Output:**

```
Two numbers in the list added together is 14. 10 4
```

Comment: The `combinations()` function makes for a *compact* solution, but is it a *good* solution?  Consider if there is no answer for a list of length N.  We need to do roughly N - 1 subtractions to determine this.  A combinations-based solution will require (N - 1) + (N - 2) + (N - 3) + ... (N - 0) additions.  E.g if the list has 10 elements, we should be able to fail it with roughly 9 subtractions, but your combinations-based approach will require 45 additions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a simple approach with no additional libraries.  But we will exploit Python's new walrus `:=` operator:

```
def add_to_k(numbers, k):
    pairs = []

    while numbers:
        if (b := k - (a := numbers.pop())) in numbers:
            pairs.append((a, b))
            numbers.remove(b)

    return pairs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [10, 15, 2, 7]

    k = 17

    if pairs := add_to_k(numbers, k):
        for pair in pairs:
            print("{} + {} = {}".format(*pair, k))
    else:
        print("Sorry, no solution for {}".format(k))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
7 + 10 = 17
2 + 15 = 17
>
```

In addition to finding multiple solutions if they exist, the result of this `add_to_k()` can also be treated as a boolean to say whether any solution exists.  This solution should handle problems like `k = 18` and `numbers = [9, 9]` vs. `numbers = [9]` correctly.